# Post to Friend's Wall with iOS Facebook SDK

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

Is it possible to use the iOS Facebook SDK's `dialog` method to post to the active user's friends' walls? That is, assuming the correct permissions have been granted?

Using the dialog method, with `"feed"` as the action, only seems to allow me to post to the user's stream, not to anyone elses. What am I missing?

`[facebook dialog:"feed" andParams:... andDelegate:self]`

The `params` only specify the content of the post; there doesn't seem to be any way to specify the profile I want to post to.

Comment: Could you post the code you're currently using?

Comment: Updated now. Although I should say, I understand why this doesn't do what I want it to. I'm wonderig whether what I want to do is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following code:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"[IdOfFriend]/feed" andParams:... andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

post on friends wall through graph path no more works
your feed action works.. have params like

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Checkout my APP_NAME", @"name",
                                   @"Come visit my APP_NAME", @"caption",
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just joined APP_NAME Can you?"], @"description",
                                   @"http://www.friendsmash.com/images/logo_large.jpg", @"picture",
                                   @"FRIEND'S_FB_USER_ID", @"to",

                                   // Add the link param for Deep Linking
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://YOUR_WEB_LINK.com/"], @"link",
                                   nil];
```

Cheers...!